# p:ajax refreshes whole page - JSF - primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, ajax-update

I have few views which will be conditionally rendered through `ajax`. Below is how my `main.xhtml`

```
<h:panelGroup id="page">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGroup
            rendered="#{myCtrl.selectedPage == 'home'}">
                <ui:include src="/home.xhtml" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGroup
            rendered="#{myCtrl.selectedPage == 'bcn'}">
                <ui:include src="/reports.xhtml" id="reportPage" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="remitid">
        <h:panelGroup
            rendered="#{myCtrl.selectedPage == 'btc'}">
            <ui:include src="/btc.xhtml" id="btcPage" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

So, based on `commandLink` click, these views will be rendered.

**Disclaimer - Earlier this was `richfaces` project which was moved to primefaces and hence instead of `a4j:support` we are using `p:ajax`**

in `reports.xhtml` I have some fields for which I have some `p:ajax` event for `onchange`.

```
<ui:composition lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <div>
        <p:inputText styleClass="datepicker" id="fromDate"
            value="#{repBean.fromDate}">
            <p:ajax event="change" update="fromDate"
                listener="#{repBean.checkForValues}"></p:ajax>
        </p:inputText>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p:inputText styleClass="datepicker" id="toDate"
            value="#{repBean.toDate}">
            <p:ajax event="change" update="toDate"
                listener="#{repBean.checkForValues}"></p:ajax>
        </p:inputText>
    </div>
</ui:composition>
```

Whenever `change event` occurs, it refreshes the view [no reload] and renders initial screen. I've also tried adding `process="@this"`/`process="@form"` and `partialSubmit="true"` to `p:ajax` but that didn't help much. As per my observation while debugging, this is not hitting bean method at all.

What's actually happening here? Why isn't `ajax` not working as expected?

Please let me know if I've to add anymore details relating to the Question.

Comment: ui:include doesn't have an `id` attribute. It's a Facelet templating tag, not a component.